# I want to test a submission form but the click on the submit button calls on a api from a different domain in Cypress

Tags: automation, cross-domain, integration-testing, cypress

Lets say I want to automate a lead form with name and number in cypress,
I click on Submit button
The BaseUrl is https://localhost:8080
On clicking the Submit button manually, an API is triggered with URL https://localhost:9010
But in Cypress
Api is not triggered , and no action occurs on clicking the submit button .
Can somebody give a solution or a workaround for this issue??

Comment: Can you post the code snippet as well as the error screenshot that your are getting ?

Comment: It is possible that you have ended the test case without a proper assertion. In such cases the test passes with false positive result.. I suggest copy the apy request from the manual testing, put is as an alliased route https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Syntax and wait and use an assertion on the result..